# How to create a button like "facebook like"

Tags: jquery

I am at a total loss with this, I need to create a "like button" like the facebook like button, I have tried to use jquery to do this but havent got anywhere. I need to basically add a row to a mysql db and then update the number of "likes" next to the button ont he page all without a refresh.

Can anyone help with this as I am totally stuck as i dont know javascript or jquery :(

Hope someone can as its been driving me nuts :)

Comment: What have you tried? Show some example code and people will be much happier to help. Where are you having the problem - do you already have the server-side script to update the database or do you need help with that too?

Comment: @James I have the server side script thats not a problem. I havent added any of the javascript code because it just doesnt work in the way i want it to, so didnt think there was any point :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basics I think?

**Your Button**

```
<div id="likeMe">Like This</div>
```

**Your call back div**

```
<div style="display: none" class="addlike">loading...</div>
```

**Your Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#likeMe").click(function() { 
$(".addlike").delay(10000).load("savelike.php?page_id=<?php echo $p;?>&user=<?php echo $user_id;?>&msd=" + new Date().getTime());  
});
</script>
```

**Your php save page**
savelike.php

```
$page_id = $_REQUEST["page_id"];
$user = $_REQUEST["user"];
$sql ="INSERT INTO MYLIKES SET user = '$user' && page_id = '$page_id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot query the database." . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

The most logical way to update a database using javascript is to create an API using a server side language that would allow you to call a URL that would increment the value in the database.

For example you would have a url http://www.example.com/ajax/incrementLikes.php

and then you would use a bit of jQuery to call that URL on click of the button e.g.

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax/incrementLikes.php'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have something like the following database model to store users and posts information:

[image: Sample database diagram]

Relationships:

Users.UserID => Posts.UserID

Users.UserID => Likes.UserID

Posts.PostID => Likes.PostID

---

When a user clicks the `Like/Unlike` button for a post, you should add/remove a record in `Likes` table. For showing the likes count, you can simply count the rows with a specific `PostID` in likes table.

You can use `JQuery` `Post()` method to post form to the server without reloading the whole page. Your like button will be something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:$.Post("YourPageUrl.php", { action: "Like", postID: <?php CODE TO GENERATE POSTID ?> }, changeLikeStatusForThisPost(<?php CODE TO GENERATE POSTID ?>));"><?php CODE TO GENERATE LIKE OR UNLIKE TEXT?></a>
```